# DHCP split-scope using Windows 2008 and Windows 2012 servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, dhcp, windows-server-2012

Can I configure DHCP split scope using our current Windows 2008 server with DHCP, and a new Windows 2012 server which I have installed DHCP on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Really the 2 servers don't share info in a split scope setup so if you manually configure each scope (80/20 or whatever) then sure, it will work.

However, if you have the ability to make both DHCP servers 2012 servers that would allow you to use Failover instead.  A better option that allows for load balancing and replication of scope information/leases between the 2.

But yeah, basically you can run a 2008 DHCP server and a 2012 DHCP server in a split scope.  Technically you could run a 2012 DHCP server and a Linux DHCP server in split scope if you wanted to.

Comment: I did know about the new failover feature in 2012 but the 2008 server is 32 bit :( thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can always configure a split scope manually between any two DHCP servers.

With Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012 there is a split scope wizard that can assist you in splitting the scope.